# Clean way of passing variable to partial view

Tags: php, model-view-controller, design-patterns

I'm looking for a clean way to pass variables to partial views. Consider the following example code:

In my controller I do:

```
$this->view->articles = $arrayWithArticles;
$this->render('articles.phtml');
```

In my *articles.phtml* view I do:

```
foreach($this->articles as $article) {
    // show article

    $this->render('comments.phtml');
}
```

In another controller I do:

```
$this->view->products = $arrayWithProducts;
$this->render('products.phtml');
```

In my *products.phtml* view I do:

```
foreach($this->products as $product) {
    // show product

    $this->render('comments.phtml');
}
```

As you can see I use the same (partial) view *comments.phtml* to display comments about written articles as well as products. The 'comments' I want to display are in `$article->comments` and `$product->reviews`. The partial view will need these to display them.

What would be a clean way to pass them to the partial view. I really don't want to do:

```
$this->comments = $article->comments;
$this->render('comments.phtml');
```

Because this would potentially become a pain to keep track off (i.e. setting the same view variables in both the controller as in the view).

Is there a clean solution to pass variables to partial views?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think adding a parameter to your `render()` method would be sufficient.  Maybe something like...

```
$this->renderSubView($fileName, $data);
```

Then in `renderSubView()` you could do whatever it is that you need to do with the array and return the rendered partial view.  This way you don't need to redeclare the variable in view, just pass the data appropriate for that specific partial when it is being rendered.